# Filter values from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string-comparison

I want to write an `array_cmp` function that works like this:

```
$variable = Array(
    [0] => Array( [id]=>"1" [file]=>"new" )
    [1] => Array( [id]=>"2" [file]=>"sample" )
    [2] => Array( [id]=>"3" [file]=>"new" )
    [3] => Array( [id]=>"4" [file]=>"garden" )
    [4] => Array( [id]=>"5" [file]=>"new" )
    [5] => Array( [id]=>"6" [file]=>"tem" )
);
$compare = "new";

$new_array = array_cmp($variable, $compare);
print_r($new_array);
```

Desired output (condensed):

```
Array(
    [0] => Array( [id]=>"1" [file]=>"new" )
    [1] => Array( [id]=>"3" [file]=>"new" )
    [2] => Array( [id]=>"5" [file]=>"new" )
);
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking us to write `array_cmp` for you?

Comment: you are searching for [array_filter](http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) where the callback has to worry about the "structure" of the input array in order to make the comparison. Pack it into a function like `array_cmp` and it's done.

Comment: I just Asked is there any function for above problem... and i used "array_cmp" for explaination .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Working `array_filter` approach

You are looking for [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$variable = array_filter($variable, function($elem) {
    return isset($elem['file']) && $elem['file'] == 'new';
});
```

## Broken `foreach` approach

Be sure not do delete unwanted elements in a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop as it has no well-defined behavior. The following code **does not work**!

```
foreach ($variable as $elem) {
    if (array_key_exists('file', $elem) && $elem['file'] != 'new') {
        unset($elem['file']);
    }
}
```

Once again: this approach is broken. You must not modify an array while looping over it with a `foreach` loop.

Also see the difference in `isset` and [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php): `isset` is false for an used key with `NULL` value.

## Working `foreach` approach

If you want to use `foreach` loop, you have to use a new array to store the results. This possibility has already been covered by [jszobody’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21065275/2157640).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($variable AS $item) {
    if($item['file'] == "new") $newarray[] = $item;
}
```

See here: http://3v4l.org/N8Mum

Comment: It is a good idea to test whether `$item` contains `file` key, as otherwise PHP will not like accessing `$item['file']`.

Comment: @Palec Sure, but we're working with the array he gave us, where he apparently knows the key exists. If you're working with an array where you don't have that confidence, by all means check.